# Find distance between point and non-linear curve

Tags: probability

The following question is in the context of learning discriminant non-linear functions using the Support Vector Machine (SVM) classifier.

So, let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be the decision function of an SVM using the radial basis function (RBF) as a kernel, i.e.
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{SV}}k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_i)+\rho,
$$
where $\mathbf{x}_i\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $i=1,\ldots,N_{SV}$ are given support vectors, $\rho\in\Bbb{R}$ is an offset term, and
$$
k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')=\exp\Big(-\gamma\Vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}' \Vert^2\Big)
$$
is the RBF kernel with given $\gamma>0$ paramater.

Now, given an unseen, testing vector, $\mathbf{x}_t\in\Bbb{R}^n$, the classifier decides its label by evaluating $f(\mathbf{x}_t)$. Thus, the predicted label, $y_t\in\{\pm1\}$, of $\mathbf{x}_t$ is given by the sign of $f(\mathbf{x}_t)$, i.e., $y_t=\operatorname{sgn}\big(f(\mathbf{x}_t)\big)$.

Besides the label I would like to find a probabilistic measure giving the "confidence" of such label assignment.

In the case of a linear decision function, i.e., $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b$, I take the sigmoid of the (signed) distance $d_t=\frac{\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$, that is,
$$
p_t = \frac{1}{1+e^{-d_t}},
$$
which seems to work for me sufficiently. However, this does not work in case of non-linear decision function, like that I give above. That is, if I give the value of $f(\mathbf{x}_t)$ in the sigmoid, it does not work, and I guess this should be expected.

What should I do in order to get such a probabilistic degree of confidence?

Should I find the distance of the testing vector $\mathbf{x}_t$ from the boundary $f(\mathbf{x})=0$? Is that even possible in the case of the RBF kernel? That is 
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{SV}}\exp\Big(-\gamma\Vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_i \Vert^2\Big)+\rho.
$$

Thank you very much!